# System.IO.IOException ErrorCodes

Tags: c#, ioexception, error-code

So I'm getting the following error when trying to print to a Zebra printer from my web application:

> Type : System.IO.IOException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089 Message : Printer is
>   \172.16.0.244\Zebra2844.  Error code is: 5

Can anybody provide some insight as to what the "Error code is: 5" represents? (Googling so far has yet to yield anything relevent)  The offending error doesn't happen when I run the web app locally from my machine, so I'm guessing that either the server the web app is hosted on either can't resolve the IP, or its a permission issue, or something like that.

Ideally, i'd like to confirm that it's the case if possible.

Anyone have any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: For the future, `net helpmsg [number]` is sometimes helpful: for `5` it gives `Access is denied.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a Windows error code.

[System error codes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381%28VS.85%29.aspx)

In the case of error 5, it's an Access Denied error.  Which is probably in your stack trace somewhere.

Comment: Awesome;  Just as I thought.  My mistake was thinking that the error code was specific to IOExceptions, and not looking at the Windows ones.  Thanks!